# insertar componente dentro de otro componente angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Quiero mostrar un componente (un header) dentro de otro, el problema, creo, es que estoy usando **router-outlet**, y cuando en alguna vista de algun componente (componente padre) quiero meter el componente header (componente hijo), y luego contenido propio del componente padre:

```
<!--archivo ComponentePadre.html -->

<app-header><app-header> <!--aqui incluyo el selector del componente hijo -->

<div class="container-fluid text-center barnav">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/cursos']" >Mis Cursos</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/agenda']">Mi Agenda</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/pacientes']">Mis Pacientes</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
```

Solo me muestra el contenido del componente hijo y nada del componente padre. 
Sin embargo me di cuenta que si incluyo el selector del componente hijo  al final del archivo si me muestra tanto el contenido del componente padre como el del componente hijo.

Tambien corrobore que ambos componentes esten importados en el archivo *app.module.ts*

Comment: Debe fallarte algo más, porque esa plantilla es correcta y debería mostrar el contenido de <app-header> seguido de todo el resto de HTML. `<router-outlet>` no afecta al comportamiento de los componentes ¿Puedes intentar crear un ejemplo mínimo de tu escenario que se puede ejecutar? O , al menos, añade más código a tu pregunta

Comment: Así a vote prontio te falta cerrar la etiqueta app-header:

<app-header></app-header>  Pero no vendría mal algo más de código.

Comment: al parecer si era solo el cerrar la etiqueta XD